# Creating a colored line_mapbox with plotly in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I created a Geodataframe with the Format:

| geometry | travel_time |
| --- | --- |
| LINESTRING (13.7369788 51.0166317) | 20.4 |
| LINESTRING (13.7352592 51.0170635, 13.7342507 51.0170325) | 18.3 |

(just as a sample)

On the Homepage of Plotly I found these codesniped
[Source](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/)

```py
lats = []
lons = []
names = []

for feature, name in zip(geo_df.geometry, geo_df.name):
    if isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString):
        linestrings = [feature]
    elif isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString):
        linestrings = feature.geoms
    else:
        continue
    for linestring in linestrings:
        x, y = linestring.xy
        lats = np.append(lats, y)
        lons = np.append(lons, x)
        names = np.append(names, [name]*len(y))
        lats = np.append(lats, None)
        lons = np.append(lons, None)
        names = np.append(names, None)
```

I modified it as follows:

```py
for feature, time in zip(self.gdf_edges.geometry, self.gdf_edges.travel_time):
            if isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString):
                linestrings = [feature]
            elif isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString):
                linestrings = feature.geoms
            else:
                continue
            for linestring in linestrings:
                x, y = linestring.xy
                lats = np.append(lats, y)
                lons = np.append(lons, x)
                times = np.append(times, [time] * len(y))
                lats = np.append(lats, None)
                lons = np.append(lons, None)
                times = np.append(times, None)
```

---

Now i want to plot these Data with plotly. That works well so far...

```py
fig = px.line_mapbox(lat=lats, lon=lons)

        # Set the graph layout
        fig.update_layout(
            mapbox=dict(
                zoom=12,
                style="carto-positron"
            ),
        )

        fig.show()
```

[image: That works well]

But if I want to add color it looks like as followed:

```py
fig = px.line_mapbox(lat=lats, lon=lons, color=times)

        # Set the graph layout
        fig.update_layout(
            mapbox=dict(
                zoom=12,
                style="carto-positron"
            ),
        )

        # Show the interactive plot
        fig.show()
```

[image: That did not work]

Do you have an idea what is my problem?

I tried to find a solution but did not succeeded...